# Can't run html pages in empty asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

I am following some instructions to learn angularjs and WebAPi, but am running into an issue creating a new empty project.
Everytime I try to run the index.html page that I created in wwwroot, I am getting a 404 error.
If I just load the index.html from file explorer, it works fine.

Since I have been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a while, I decided to try to create a new Web Application project, to see if the starter project will work, and it works fine, including the index.html that copied from my other project.
So I am confused as to why I cant get iis to launch my pages in an empty project solution, I tried to recreate it 4 times, using a combination of either Microsoft.ASPnetcore.MVC as a dependency, or reverting back to Microsoft.ASPnet.Mvc

This is what my project.json's dependences looks like

```
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

},

I also compared it to the Web Application templete, and aside from the logger dependencies, there is nothing different.
I don't want to use the web application template, as it takes more time to remove all the junk that I don't need for my upcoming projects.

Any help would be appreciated.

`

Comment: Have you tried .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) in Program.Main() ?

Comment: Program.main already had that by default, but the strange thing is, now all of a sudden I can get my page to load properly, after it not working right the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

It started working fine this morning, although I can only use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, my applications no longer like the old references to Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc